# How to register custom menu widget

Tags: menus, widgets

I'm trying to register a custom menu widget programmatically with [`wp_register_sidebar_widget`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget), but it doesn't appear in wordpress. I'm using remote call of that method (xml-rpc). Referring to codex I'm passing parametres like that to that method:

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget(
    'custom_menu_widget-1',
    'My name',
    'WP_Nav_Menu_Widget',
    array( 'description' => 'blogroll' )
);
```

It should create custom menu widget named 'My name', but it registers nothing. I think that third parameter `$output_callback` may be wrong, but I can't find nowhere, what callback should be for custom menus. I've got no output or error from that call, so I can't see what is wrong. Maybe I miss something or there is another way to register custom menu widget? I don`t want to edit function.php, I just want to register standard custom menu widget using wp methods.

Comment: I am not sure this is even supposed to work. Could you elaborate on what exactly you are doing with XML-RPC here?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code (in `function.php`)

```
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'description' => __('Use this widget to add one of your custom menu as a link list widget.') );
        parent::__construct( 'custom_menu_widget-1', __('My name'), $widget_ops );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        // Get menu
        $nav_menu = ! empty( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] ) : false;

        if ( !$nav_menu )
            return;

        $instance['title'] = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );



        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];

        wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $nav_menu) );

        echo $args['after_widget'];

    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['title']) );
        $instance['nav_menu'] = (int) $new_instance['nav_menu'];
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $nav_menu = isset( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? $instance['nav_menu'] : '';

        // Get menus
        $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

        // If no menus exists, direct the user to go and create some.
        if ( !$menus ) {
            echo '<p>'. sprintf( __('No menus have been created yet. <a href="%s">Create some</a>.'), admin_url('nav-menus.php') ) .'</p>';
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>"><?php _e('Select Menu:'); ?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nav_menu'); ?>">
        <?php
            foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
                $selected = $nav_menu == $menu->term_id ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option'. $selected .' value="'. $menu->term_id .'">'. $menu->name .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );

function myplugin_register_widgets() {

      register_widget( 'MyWidget' );

}
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply Amino, but I forgot mention that I can`t edit function.php. I`m working on many sites with remote calls of wp methods (xml-rpc). I don`t want to create a new class of widget, but just register standard custom menu widget, which I can add to sidebar. When You drag&drop custom menu widget to sidebar You don`t have to add code to function.php. Wp just call some method with apropriate parametres, but reading source code of widgets.php and widgets.js doesn`t give me an answer.

Comment: oh! so, I don't know :D